# Sox conversion from .au to .wav

Tags: audio, data-conversion, sox

I have a file, sound.au, which `file` describes as `Sun/NeXT audo data: 8-bit ISDN mu-law, mono, 8000 Hz`.  I'd like to convert this to a WAV that `file` would describe as `RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000 Hz`.  However, I cannot get the right set of arguments to make this conversion and see what it sounds like.

Has anyone performed this conversion or similar before?  `sox -t auto -w -s -r 8000 -c sound.au sound.wav` gets me close, but it's G711 mu-law, not 16 bit PCM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an `.au` file to try, but I suspect `sox sound.au -e signed-integer sound.wav` would work. You are only trying to change the encoding from u-law to PCM, right? `sox` should pick up all the necessary input info from the `.au` header. If it doesn't, maybe you need `sox -t auto sound.au -e signed-integer sound.wav`.